# How to send entire logs to jaeger span

Tags: go, jaeger

Is there any way to put the std logs provided by the application and the errors to a span?

I know that I can send some logs with `span.LogKV()` or `span.LogFields()` but it makes code look bad while there are same logs with both application logger and span logger.

I'm looking for an automated way to put all logs to the corresponding span.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot with auto configuration, the logs printed using log4j will be instrumented and sent automatically in the span.

Answer (score 0):

In Go this is not very straightforward, and largely depends on the logging library you use and the interface it provides. One example is implemented in the [HotROD demo](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/tree/master/examples/hotrod) in the Jaeger repository and it is described in the [blog post accompanying the demo](https://medium.com/opentracing/take-opentracing-for-a-hotrod-ride-f6e3141f7941). It uses `go.uber.org/zap` logging library underneath and allows to write log statements accepting the Context argument:

```golang
logger.For(ctx).Info(
    "Searching for nearby drivers",
    zap.String("location", location),
)
```

Behind the scenes `logger.For(ctx)` captures the current tracing spans and adds all log statements to that span, in addition to sending then to `stdout` as usual.

To my knowledge, `go.uber.org/zap` does not yet support this mode of logging natively, and therefore requires a wrapper.

If you use another logging library, than on the high level this is what needs to happen:

1. there must be a way to pass the Context to the logging methods, which could be captured internally by the logging framework in the log message data structure
2. the "appender" (or whatever it's called, I am using log4j terminology) that's responsible for taking log messages and writing them to some output stream can be extended to retrieve the Span from the Context and write the log message to the Span using `span.LogKV()` or similar API.